# Query not working express.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I have a problem with a query using express.js. Citta_p and Citta_a are two arrays and what I want is that my query gives me all the ids for all the cities. Instead, what I get is just the last value, it's like my cycle starts from var i = 1 and I never get the values for i = 0. Anyone can help me?
This is my code:

page.html

```
<div class = "container" id = "nuova_linea" style= "display : none">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style = "margin-top: 100px;">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/inseriscilinea">
        <div class='alert alert-error'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>

        <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center header">Inserisci una nuova linea </legend>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" style = "margin-left: 200px">Nome Linea: </label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_linea" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" style = "margin-left: 200px">Numero fermate: </label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero_fermate" name = "numero"></div>
        <div><input type="button" onclick = "AggiungiFermate()" class = "btn btn-primary" id="button" value="Invia">
    </div>
</div>

<div id = "contenitore"></div>

<div id = "miefermate" style = "display : none">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" style = "margin-left: 200px">Città di partenza: </label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_citta_p" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" style = "margin-left: 200px">Città di arrivo: </label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_citta_a" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" style = "margin-left: 200px">Km: </label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="km" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id = "salva" style = "display : none">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
</div>
```

```
</div>

</div>

</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    function AggiungiFermate() {
        for(var i=0;i<$("#numero_fermate").val();i++) {
            $("#contenitore").append($("#miefermate").html())
        }
        $("#salva").show("slow");
    }
</script>
```

page.js

```
exports.insertLine = function(req,res) {



var linea = req.body.nome_linea;
var numero = req.body.numero;
var citta_p = req.body.nome_citta_p;
var citta_a = req.body.nome_citta_a;


var km = req.body.km;



req.getConnection(function(err,connection) {

for(var i=0;i<numero;i++) {

  var sql = connection.query("select c.id,cc.id from città as c, città as cc where (c.nome = ? and cc.nome = ?)",[citta_p[i],citta_a[i]], function(err,rows) {

    if(err) console.log("%s", err);

    if(rows.length > 0) {
      console.log(rows);

      }
    }
  });
}


});

};
```

Comment: in Node.js IO is async. A loop wont work. You can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for flow control.

Comment: yes it can be but I think that the query is wrong because if I write the query without the second array it works. Even when I don't have any cycle but 2 strings/arrays which I want the ids, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insertLine` should look something like this:

```
// npm install async
var async = require('async');

exports.insertLine = function(req,res) {
  var linea   = req.body.nome_linea;
  var numero  = req.body.numero;
  var citta_p = req.body.nome_citta_p;
  var citta_a = req.body.nome_citta_a;
  var km      = req.body.km;

  req.getConnection(function(err,connection) {
    var q = "select c.id,cc.id from città as c, città as cc where (c.nome = ? and cc.nome = ?)";
    async.times(numero,function(i,next){
      connection.query(q,[citta_p[i],citta_a[i]],function(err,rows){
        if(err) return next(err);
        console.log(i,rows);
        next(null,rows);
      });
    },function(err,rows){
      if(err) res.send('error');
      else if(!rows || !rows.length) res.redirect('/somewhere')
      else res.send('ok');
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I have another problem now, sorry! After the result of my query I need to use res.redirect() but I can't because of async. How can I do that?
--> if(rows.length > 0) {
                res.redirect('/lines');

            }

Comment: @simonav Updated the answer, hope it helps!